# Save lines import from another google spreadsheet

Tags: dataframe, function, google-sheets

I am doing dynamic google spreadsheet (1), multiple personne are going to add some data in it. At the same time an other google spreadsheet (2) is going to register those informations.
I use the function =IMPORTRANGE to move data from one sheet to another.

I want to know if there is a way to save the data in the seucond spreadsheet when the data are removed from the first one.

Thank you.

Comment: not possible with importrange

Comment: Is there an other way to do that ?

Comment: You've to use Google Apps Script for this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Apps Script!

For your situation, a good idea is to make use of Apps Script. Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with Google Workspace.

A way to monitor the changes in a spreadsheet is to use an `onEdit` trigger. Therefore, whenever data is removed from your first spreadsheet you can easily save it in the second one as `onEdit` will trigger every time a user edits a spreadsheets. You will have to write your own code in order to manage this according to your needs. A short example can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview);
- [Apps Script Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).